# Can I just multiply my independant variable by 100 to make interpretation more clear (it is an index that takes values between 0 and 1)?

Tags: econometrics

I am trying to see if there's a relationship between academic freedom (independant variable) and university rankings (dependant variable) using a fixed effects model.

I managed to get some significant results, but the problem is that since academic freedom goes from 0 to 1, the coefficients are really extreme.
For example, I get a coefficient of -400, meaning that if academic freedom went from 0 (its lowest possible value) to 1 (it's highest possible value), a university would gain 400 ranks in a ranking.

Such interpretations are nonsensical since no country ever goes from the lowest academic freedom to the highest. For most countries, academic freedom always varies around a certain mean value (for all years, France's academic freedom will always be around 0.9; sometimes higher, sometimes lower, but it will never dramatically decrease. Same for China, for example : it might increase or decrease, but it stays around 0.2.)

Having this in mind, can I just multiply academic freedom by 100 in order to have coefficients that are easier to interpet ? Or will this transformation mess up my model and the relationship between my variables ?

From what I saw, such a transformation could work, the only thing I have to take into account is that the coefficient will now be interpeted as a change of ranking when academic freedom goes up 1%. Is that true ? Or are there some other things that I haven't taken into account that forbid me from transforming my dependant variable ?

Answer (score 2):

In principle, yes. Except that you can only interpret the change in new variable as a precentage if the old variable is a proportion. That does not seem to be the case. Instead you need to do some linguistic gymnastics to find a true *and* clear representation of what your unit now means. I think the effort is worth it, but it is still an effort.

Comment: Thanks ! As for the interpretation, wouldn't it just be how much the ranking varies when academic freedom goes up by 0.01 points (since 0.01 is just 1 divided by 100) ? Or is it more complex than that ?

Comment: Sure, but what does 0.01 point mean in substantive terms...